# C# project, can't reset/clear array, setting array to zero not the answer

Tags: c#, arrays

*problem solved*

I am working on a project where an array holds the scores of 5 tests, but the user does not have to fill the array with 5 scores total. there is a button that displays a message box that lists the 5 scores values. The user needs to be able to run the program twice in a row without restarting the program, every time the 2nd round comes around, the array is still holding the last rounds values. I can't set the values to zero, because a live average is calculated and displayed after each score is entered, and the zeros throw off the average.

This is the button that displays the scores. If the user enters fewer than 5 scores (5 is size of array) the message box should display only those 4 or less scores, the way I have it now, it is displaying zeroes for the unused values.

```
 private void btnDisplayScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++)
      {
        Convert.ToString(scoreArray[x]);
       }
      MessageBox.Show(scoreArray[0] + Environment.NewLine 
               + scoreArray[1] + Environment.NewLine + scoreArray[2] 
               + Environment.NewLine+ scoreArray[3] + Environment.NewLine 
               + scoreArray[4]);
```

We have only learned to use null with strings, we have not gotten into nullable integers and decimals. We are expected to do it without using a nullable numerical type.

This resets the values so the user can start another round.

```
    private void Restart()
    {
        scoreTotal = 0;
        txtScore.Clear();
        txtScoreTotal.Clear();
        txtScoreCount.Clear();
        txtAverage.Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x <= counter; x++)
        {
            scoreArray[x] = 0;
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
```

And maybe this will help.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          int currentScore;
          if (counter < 5)
            {
              if (DataValid() && DataRange())
                {
                    currentScore = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
                    Input(currentScore);
                    Process();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data was invalid, please enter valid data.", "Error");
                }
                counter++;
            }
           else
            {
                Restart();
            }
            txtScore.Focus();
        }
```

edit* i mistakenly thought i needed to convert the array to string to display it in the message box, fixed that but its not at the core of my problem.

i may try to the -1 suggestion tonite or tommarow

havnt learned list yet, array is declared global

edit2* problem solved, used the -1 solution, thanks to mfussenegger

Comment: Are you allowed to use `List<T>` instead of an ordinary array? BTW: You haven't shown us how `scoreArray` is declared.

Comment: What do you expect the calls to `Convert.ToString` to do? You're not doing anything with the results.

Comment: You could also use -1 for unassigned and ignore those values when displaying the average.